# automatically update row after certain time

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I made a website where my users can post ads.

Now I want to automatically change one row in their Ads table after a certain time.

Eg: Let say that my user uploads/posts an AD, and before he posts it he gets the choose if he wants to keep it visible for 8 days or 16 days.

Should I check this with a cron or is there a better way to do it?

Visible is called "active" the DB, -  tinyint 1 or 0.

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options to manage this both based on the timescale they select.

1. Store an expiration time with the ad and include expiration > NOW(); in any queries to select ads (this kind of negates the requirement for an 'active' field.
2. use an event to manage this.

Method 1 may require some admin to 'clean up ads' periodically.

Method 2 - you can't create events in a procedure yet (last time I checked) but they allow you to set and forget these kind of admin duties without having to run other checks and what-nots.

Each event must have a unique name otherwise you will kill the event already specified...

example:

```
<?php

$qry = "insert into ads values ( 'x', 'y', 'z' );"; 
/* db execute qry (pdo or what ever) */
$adId = // retriev a unique reference for ad.
$days = $_POST['expire'] == 16 ? 16 : 8;

$qry = "CREATE EVENT updateAd_".$adId."
    ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL ".$days." DAY
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
    DO
    update ads set active = 'false' where ad_id = ".$adId.";";
// db execute qry (pdo or what ever);
?>
```

The event is stored in the mysql database and not your own so you need some admin level permissions to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Can you keep the expiry date instead? So create a column in which you store the date. When the user creates the Ad then calculate the date 8 days from now and store that in the column. Then in your query to pull the ad you can restrict to those ads whose expiry dates are still in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Store the expiration date. Then use the query :

```
select * from table where Expiration_date>now();
```

If you're using PHP check out the [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function. You can use it to create your date like so:

```
$expiration = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime('+ '.$num.'days'));
```

If you have the 'Expiration_date' field the 'active' field is not necessary. 
The statement

```
select Expiration_date>now() as active from table
```

would be equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!

Sorry I asked my qustion all wrong.

What I ment was I want to add some sort of timer, so that after 8 or 16 days the "active" field will change from 1 to 0, true/false.

I have both both time when posted and expiration_time in the table as well.


Thanks!

Comment: If you have the 'Expiration_date' field the 'active' field is not necessary. The statement "select Expiration_date>now() as active from table" would be equivalent.