# table update after certain time in postgreSql

Tags: php, postgresql

I have create table in postgres, now i want to update one row after certain time (eg: 1 hour).

i see many question like :

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/56424/column-auto-updated-after-24-hours-in-mysql
[automatically update row after certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15400342/automatically-update-row-after-certain-time)

but i dont know how this is work in Postgres, plz help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL doesn't have native support for scheduling jobs. The two most common solutions involve pgAgent and cron.

[pgAgent](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/pgagent.html) is "a job scheduling agent for PostgreSQL, capable of running multi-step batch/shell and SQL tasks on complex schedules."

The cron program is a system daemon that executes programs at certain times. Almost every operating system includes cron or something like it; Windows has Windows Task Scheduler.