# how to update value a certain time later with postgresql

Tags: database, postgresql, function, time, database-trigger

I have a trigger function where data will be updated after a certain time.

I have seen many questions already, but not found my solution.
You can see [table update after certain time in postgreSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894243/table-update-after-certain-time-in-postgresql)

## My trigger function

```
create or replace function truncate_data()
returns trigger as
$BODY$
    begin
    if TO_CHAR(current_timestamp, 'hh12:mi:ss AM') = ('11:59:59 PM') then
    --if current_time = '23:59:59+06' then
    update employee set (lts_O, interval_time, total_interval_time, out_count, login, logout, login_count) = (null, null, null, null, null, null, null) where pid = new.pid and today = current_date;
    end if;
    return new;
    end;
$BODY$
language plpgsql;

create trigger truncate_data
before update
on employee
for each row
execute procedure truncate_data()
```

But this trigger doesn't work when the current_time match with my initial time.

Thanks for advance.

Comment: If you want delayed execution of a trigger, there is no such thing. You'd best use a queue of some description where you enter the primary key of the row. Later a worker reads entries from the queue and performs the action. This is something you have to write yourself. If you want to do this in the database, you can resort to extensions that already implement queues, like `pgq`.

Comment: @Laurenz Albe thanks. Please, can you give me a sample such as?

Comment: Is this supposed to implement some kind of daily reset? If so, you might want to take a look at [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/). As a completely different alternative, I'd suggest not just using counters but instead have a real audit log and just calculate the counters on demand. A daily-rollover can be achieved then at query time and/or at partition level if you are willing to use an automatic time-based partitioning extension such as [timescale](https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb/).